# Django Queryset of related objects, after prefiltering on original model

Tags: django, django-models

Given a queryset for one model, I want to get a queryset of another model that is related by foreign key. Take the Django project docs' weblog schema:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    mod_date = models.DateField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    n_comments = models.IntegerField()
    n_pingbacks = models.IntegerField()
    rating = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.headline
```

Suppose I have an `author` object, and I want to get every blog that author has written for, as a queryset.  I do something like `author_blogs = [entry.blog for entry in author.entry_set]`.  But I'm left with a list in this case, not a queryset.  Is there a way I can do this directly with ORM queries, so I can set it up via a custom Entry manager with `use_for_related_fields = True` and do something like `author_blogs = author.entry_set.blogs`, and get the benefits of delayed evaluation, etc., of a queryset?

**Edited scenario and solution**

So, I realized after the fact that the application of my question is slightly different than how I posed it above, for which Daniel Roseman's situation makes a lot of sense.  My situation is really more like `author.entry_set.manager_method().blogs`, where `manager_method()` returns a queryset of Entry objects.  I accepted his answer because it inspired the solution I found which is to do:

```
author_blogs = Blog.objects.filter(entry__in=author.entry_set.manager_method())
```

The nice thing is that it only uses one DB query.  It's a bit tricky and verbose, so I think it's best to define `blogs()` as an object method of Author, returning the above.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The trick for this is to remember that if you want a queryset of Blogs, you should start with the Blog model. Then, you can use the double-underscore syntax to follow relations. So:

```
author_blogs = Blog.objects.filter(entry__authors=author)
```

Comment: Yeah, that would be a great solution to the question as I originally posed it. As it turns out, my situation was slightly different. I accepted your answer though, because it inspired the solution I came up with, which I edited into my question. Thanks.

Comment: I THINK you need to have the related_name="entry"